$\text{AdS}^{n,1}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb H^n \times \mathbb S^1$
Consider the real vector space $\mathbb R^{n,2} = (\mathbb R^{n+2}, b)$ with the non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form of signature $(2,2)$ $$b(x,y) = x_1y_1 + \cdots x_ny_n -x_{n+1}y_{N+1}-x_{n+2}y_{n+2}$$
We define the quadric model of anti-de Sitter space as $$\text{AdS}^{n,1} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+2} \mid b(x,x) =-1\}$$ Let $x \in \text{AdS}^{n,1}$, then $T_x \text{AdS}^{n,1} = x^{\perp}$ and $\mathbb R^{n,2} = x \oplus x^\perp$. Now $\text{AdS}^{n,1}$ with $g_{AdS^{n,1}} = b\Big|_{x^{\perp}}$ is a Lorentzian manifold of dimension $n+1$.
Here I have proved that $AdS^{n,1}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb H^n \times S^1$ where $\mathbb H^n$ is  the hyperboloid model, where the diffeomorphism is given by   the map $f: \mathbb H^n \times S^1 \rightarrow \text{AdS}^{n,1}$, defined by $$f((x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n, r), e^{i\theta}) = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n, r cos \theta, r sin \theta).$$
My question is: can I define a map the map $f: \mathbb H^n \times S^1 \rightarrow \text{AdS}^{n,1}$, defined by $$f(u,v) = X+Y,$$  where $X$ and $Y$ has explicit description.
Can anyone please me?
